# If I send an event to a AWS Lambda function via EventBus putEvents, can I receive data back in a response?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have an EventBus set up to trigger another Lambda function (which accesses my database and retrieves data). Is there a way for the data to be returned to the location of the putEvents function?

I've tried to use a .then() to catch the response, but I've noticed that the Promise result is a EventBridge.PutEventsResponse that only contains the Event ID of successful events.

Comment: No you can't get response from the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/eventbridge) [PutEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutEvents.html), you are sending that those events to your event bus and the response your code gets is confirmation that the events were delivered to the bus. The invocation of a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) Function from a [rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html) is a decoupled, asynchronous action. And depending on your rules and targets, that could result in multiple actions.

If your code needs to have the response from the Lambda Function invocation, you probably want to just call that directly. Or depending on the nature of your use case, you may be better to compose these functions together using [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Out of curiosity, would it be practical to use http requests from one lambda to another?

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but it's often not a good idea. It may make sense for your specific scenario, but I'd suggest you look at Step Functions.